# if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) - raise a build error

Tags: apple-push-notifications, xcode6

Xcode: Version 6.0 (6A313)

push notification section taken as is from parse

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

raises the following error:

```
 Unknown receiver 'application'; did you mean 'UIApplication'?
```

Comment: Replace 'application' with '[UIApplication sharedApplication]'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code, may work for you.

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
return YES;
}
```